# Need to override following file rules.js

Tags: validation, magento2.3.3

```
magento2.3.3/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/da_DK/Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules.js
```

I need to override rules.js for specific Danish locale only for Admin area, how can I achieve that.

In short, if I describe then I need to make a small change in validate-number to support 100.000,00

```
'validate-number': [
            function (value) {
                return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) ||
                    !isNaN(utils.parseNumber(value)) && /^\s*-?\d*(.\d*)*(\,\d*)?\s*$/.test(value);
            },
```

Answer (score 2):

Create `requirejs-config.js` in `Vendor/Module/view/base/`.

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/lib/validation/rules': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Create `rules.js` in `Vendor/Module/view/base/web/js/lib/validation`.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'moment',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, _, moment) {
    'use strict';

    return function (validator) {
        var validators = {
            'validate-number-custom': [
                function (value) {
                    return /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/i.test(value);
                },
                $.mage.__('Please enter a valid number in this field.')
            ]
        };

        validators = _.mapObject(validators, function (data) {
            return {
                handler: data[0],
                message: data[1]
            };
        });

        return $.extend(validator, validators);
    };
});
```

Add your changes in return line. And use `validate-number-custom` validation for your field.

And execute `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

Comment: Can you let me know what to put in rules.js for changing default validate number rule

Comment: @Arjun See my updated answer.